# Should topic about volunteering be mentioned explicitly in the help center?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, help-center, scope

While [questions about volunteering aren't off-topic](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3603/26826), volunteering isn't mentioned explicitly in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Should this be changed? I think volunteering is a very special form of work(place), and I think it should be mentioned if those questions are allowed.

Comment: There are many things that are on-topic, but I doubt all of them can/should be mentioned explicitly (I doubt there is enough space). Besides (1) on the second link you included, second header, is specified the things that are off-topic, and volunteering doesn't seem to fall into any of those and (2) the first link you shared already provides a consensus on how to handle a question like that, for when the situation arises.

Comment: I know. But making it officially is also good. Plus I don't see why there isn't enough space. Just adding a sentence is enough

Comment: I think volunteering is a very special form of work(place) , som imo it should be mentioned if those questions are allowed. So why does this question has so many downvotes?

Comment: The name of the site itself is "Workplace", not "Paid Workplace". I support the idea that volunteering should be acceptable. Discrimination based on financial reasons is bad discrimination, IMO.

Comment: @virolino it's already allowed. It's just not explicitly allowed. For a newcomer, the help page is unclear

Comment: @Ooker: you are right, I actually meant "make it explicit".

Comment: Unpaid internships are regularly discussed here. Is volunteering so different?

Comment: Volunteering should 100% be considered a workplace topic since these people are active in, participate in, and affect workplace culture. In many organizations, they are an important part of the workforce. I think it would be remiss for us to ignore smaller, charity and non-profit based, organizations because they aren't a "standard" corporate body.